# From purrr::invoke_map to rlang::exec (translate behavior)

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

I noticed that `purrr::invoke_map()` and his relatives were retired in favour of `rlang::exec()` used in conjunction with `purrr::map`, [as documentation specified](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/invoke.html).

For some cases when you want to highlight different set of arguments to pass trough a function, `purrr::invoke_map` was very expresive, for example:

```
# create different settings of arguments in a list
args_list <- list(set1 = list(n = 5, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                  set2 = list(n = 5, mean = 10, sd = 2))

# pass each setting by the function
invoke_map(rnorm, args_list)
```

In the documentation you can find the following using `exec` + `map2` to emulate above behavior:

```
 # Before:
 invoke_map(fns, list(args))
 invoke_map(fns, list(args1, args2))

 # After:
 map(fns, exec, !!!args)
 map2(fns, list(args1, args2), function(fn, args) exec(fn, !!!args))
```

How can we translate the formerly describe pattern using `exec` + `map2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `map`, when you have to apply the same function to `args_list`.

```
library(purrr)
args_list <- list(set1 = list(n = 5, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                  set2 = list(n = 5, mean = 10, sd = 2))

map(args_list, ~exec(rnorm, !!!.x))
```

Using `map2` when you want to apply different functions

```
args_list <- list(set1 = list(n = 5, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                  set2 = list(n = 3, min = 1, max = 2))

map2(args_list, list(rnorm, runif), ~exec(.y, !!!.x))
```